# Detected link problem staring with www., replace with a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

When I am matching `http` or `https` I can convert it into `a` element, but for some reason what ever i try it wont react to `www.` can someone explain?

```js
$("[name='text']").each(function(element) {

let str = $(this).text();

if (str.match('http')||str.match('https')) {
    var link= str.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g,"<a href='$1' target='_blank' >$1</a>");
}

if (str.match('www')) {
    var link= str.replace(/(www?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g,"<a href='$1' target='_blank' >$1</a>");
}

$(this).html(link);
console.log(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="text">https://stackoverflow.com/ https link</div>
<div name="text">http://stackoverflow.com/ http link</div>
<div name="text">www.stackoverflow.com/ www link</div>
```

Comment: `www` is not a protocol and unless the link is relative to your domain won't open a different site without having a protocol (http:// or https:// etc)

Comment: @charlietfl Oh I see now,  yeah a whiteout protocol is not working. Cant believe i haven't notice this before. But i can append it i guess.

Comment: Easy to miss things like this... not like I've never had a link go to `abc.com/xyx.com`. User input of url's usually requires double checking protocol exists for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on  @charlietfl comments i wrote this for myself if someone needs it (i think it covers most cases):

```js
$("[name='text']").each(function() {

  let str = $(this).text();
  //console.log(str);
  if (str.match('www') || str.match('http') || str.match('https')) {
    var link = "";
    if (str.match('http') || str.match('https')) {
      link = str.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, "<a href='$1' target='_blank' >$1</a>");
    }

      if (str.match("www") && !str.includes("http")) {
        var str2 = str.replace("www", "http://www");
        link = str2.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, "<a href='$1' target='_blank' >$1</a>");
      }
    $(this).html(link);
    
    console.log(link);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="text">test1 https://stackoverflow.com/ https link</div>
<div name="text">test2 http://stackoverflow.com/ http link</div>
<div name="text">test3 http://www.stackoverflow.com/ http link</div>
<div name="text">test4 https://www.stackoverflow.com/ http link</div>
<div name="text">test5 www.stackoverflow.com/ link</div>
<div name="text">test6 https://www.stackoverflow.com/www-test with another www inside</div>
<div name="text">test7 nolink</div>
```